# Using Cambria Math in XeLaTeX

Tags: math-mode, xetex, accents

Take a look at the following images,

XeLaTeX typeset formula:

[image]

Word generated formula:

[image]

Note specifically the difference of the `\hat` implementations at `g_i` and `g_i^2` in XeLaTeX. In Word the two implementations are the same. Also note that the hats in XeLaTeX are both larger than Word's.

A minimum working example is the following:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}

\begin{document}
\[
V_{a_i}\left(\bar{x}_i,\hat{\theta},t\right) = -\frac{\hat{g}_i}{\hat{g}_i^2+\delta_{g_i}}V_{b_i}
\]
\end{document}
```

Why is this happening? Is there a way to make things better in XeLaTex?

Comment: we can also notice the distance between the V and a letters in `V_{a_i}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [bug in XeTeX](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2888324&group_id=194926&atid=951385). It should be fixed by now, but the fix has not made its way into TeX Live (I don't know about MikTeX). Tex Live 2012 should have updated XeTeX binaries when it is released.

In the meantime, it works fine with LuaTeX.

Comment: You should be able to compile XeTeX yourself, but for how to do that better ask a separate question.

Comment: @niels: First update your MiKTeX installation (current MiKTeX is 2.9.4503 with XeTeX 0.9997.4) and try out.

Comment: @Speravir: TL 2011 has 0.9997.5 and it doesn't work there.

Comment: @niels: you may want to get the new `unicode-math` from [github](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/), as it takes advantage of new features in XeTeX 0.9998 (plus other fixes).

Comment: @Khaled Hosny: just tried, now hats look smaller and neater than with the older version :-)