# Parentheses changing size depending on what's in them?

Tags: math-mode, lyx, scaling, delimiters

Very simple problem, but very confusing. When I type

```
\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x }  \right)^2
```

I get smaller parentheses but when I type the **same thing** but with y instead of x, i.e.

```
\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y }  \right)^2
```

I get larger ones... what's up with that? Is it a known problem or do I have to supply more information?

**UPDATE (after reading some comments)**:

This difference isn't present if the expression is written by itself, but only if it's in the denominator, i.e. when I write

```
\frac{...something...} { \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x }  \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}  \right)^2}
```

I get parentheses of different size!

Comment: Simply `y` adds more vertical space and the parenthesis in bigger. Are you looking for a solution to make them the same size?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! A solution would be nice, you can post it as an answer if you want :)

Comment: To manually control parentheses size, you can use `\big(` and `\big)`, instead of `\left(` and `\right`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38870/18228 for more size options.

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick!

Comment: The method linked by @KevinC is the right one in these cases (`\biggl` and `\biggr` seem to be the more appropriate in your case). As an alternative you can put `\vphantom{y}` next to the `x` in your first equation.

Comment: @karlkoeller: I thought the problem may be more complicated than that? `\left` and `\right` delimiters are supposed to be symmetric around math axis. However `df/dx` and `df/dy` have similar height and relatively close depth (6.9pt vs 8.8pt in display mode), so there shouldn't be any notable difference in the delimiter size. (Correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: @Francis I can not see any difference, but probably it looks different in Lyx.

Comment: @karlkoeller: Indeed, the vertical difference is less than `2pt`. But I don't use LyX so I wouldn't know. :P

Comment: @karlkoeller it must be a Lyx thing - I just tested the MWE in MikTeX 2.9, screengrabbed the pdf zoomed well in and overlaid in the gimp.  The only difference bweteen the 2 is in the denominator, _x_ and _y_ are slightly different widths, but the parentheses are exactly the same height (to 1 part in about 250).

Comment: Just to point out, the differences I was getting were obvious and noticeable right away with the naked eye.

Comment: @SchlomoSteinbergerstein You should try showing the LaTeX file produced by LyX, as the problem seems unreproducible with standard settings.

Comment: I tried to do that and I found out that it happens only when the expression is in the denominator! I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: More than interested, excellent! I really hope it grows into a high-quality community similar to mathoverflow!

Answer (score 4):

Here is an great old post that provide thorough explanation on how `\left` and `\right` work:

[**Incorrect delimiter size in math mode**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124464/incorrect-delimiter-size-in-math-mode)

Now back to your question, as karlkoeller explained, letter `y` adds more vertical space so the parenthesis become bigger. It can be observed as the following[image]

There are basically three ways to solve the problem, we can choose among redefining `\left` and `\right` (which is strongly recommended) as the post above suggested, increase the size of `df/dx`, and decrease the size of `df/dy`. The size changing can be accomplished by using `\rule` or `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength{\dyfoo}
\newlength{\hyfoo}
\newlength{\dxfoo}
\newlength{\hxfoo}
\settodepth{\dyfoo}{\(\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\)}
\settoheight{\hyfoo}{\(\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\)}
\settodepth{\dxfoo}{\(\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\)}
\settoheight{\hxfoo}{\(\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\)}

\begin{document}
\[
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vphantom{y}x}\right)
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)
\left(\raisebox{0pt}[\hyfoo][\dyfoo]{\(\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\)}\right)
\left(\raisebox{0pt}[\hxfoo][\dxfoo]{\(\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\)}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Compare the result:

[image]

**Remark:**

`\left` and `\right` delimiters are supposed to be symmetric around math axis. Hence the vertical difference in both delimiter are no larger than `2pt`. So there shouldn't be any necessity to make the adjustment.