# Why the \mleft and \mright commands inhibits the breaking between delimiters inside dmath?

Tags: delimiters, breqn

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{breqn}

\usepackage{amsmath} \delimitershortfall=-1pt

\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

  \lipsum[3-4]

  \textcolor{red}{{\ttfamily \textbackslash mleft} and {\ttfamily \textbackslash mright} inhibits the breaking between delimiters inside {\ttfamily dmath}:}

  \begin{dmath*}
    \mathcal{O}(f) = \mleft\{ t \hiderel{:} \mathbb{N} \hiderel{\rightarrow} \mathbb{R}^+_0 \hiderel{\mid} \exists c \hiderel{\in} \mathbb{R}^+ \wedge \exists n_0 \hiderel{\in} \mathbb{N} \wedge \forall n \hiderel{\geq} n_0 \wedge t(n) \hiderel{\leq} c \, f(n) \mright\}
  \end{dmath*}

  \textcolor{blue}{{\ttfamily \textbackslash left} and {\ttfamily \textbackslash right} produce a good results but {\bf is preferable in many equations always use} the {\ttfamily \textbackslash mleft} and {\ttfamily \textbackslash mright} commands:}

  \begin{dmath*}
    \mathcal{O}(f) = \left\{ t \hiderel{:} \mathbb{N} \hiderel{\rightarrow} \mathbb{R}^+_0 \hiderel{\mid} \exists c \hiderel{\in} \mathbb{R}^+ \wedge \exists n_0 \hiderel{\in} \mathbb{N} \wedge \forall n \hiderel{\geq} n_0 \wedge t(n) \hiderel{\leq} c \, f(n) \right\}
  \end{dmath*}

  \lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Are there any solution or modification that allowed to use \mleft and \mright correctly inside \dmath?**

Comment: In order to work `breqn` redefines more or less _everything_ related to math typesetting in TeX. Then you load Heiko's package and he redefines stuff again, but aimed at a normal tex setup. It's no doubt possible to rewrite mleftright in breqn style, but not working together should be the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick of `\mleft` of package `mleftright` is that it starts with an empty `\mathopen{}` and puts the whole expression inside a `\mathclose{...}` including the original delimiters with `\left` and `\right`. Thus the surrounding math sees a correctly delimited expression and `\left` and `\right` do not set their additional spacing inside `\mathclose`.

As the original `\left` and `\right`, the expression is put into a math subformula that cannot be broken across lines (`\mathinner` for `\left` and `\right`; `\mathclose` in case of `\mleft` and `\mright`). However, package `breqn` redefines `\left` and `\right` for its purpose to allow line breaks. But because they are inside a subformula, the line break will not have an effect.

Thus you can make a feature request to `breqn`, if you want to have a similiar feature that package `mleftright` provides.

But in the case of the question there is no point in using `\mleft`/`\mright` at all. The inserted space between the relational symbol (`=`) and the opening fence `\{` or a math inner formula (`\left`/`\right`) is exactly the same (`\thickmuskip`). And the closing fence ends the whole equation without a following symbol.

Comment: There isn;t really anyone maintaining `breqn` anymore. Those of us left, either do not have the time for `breqn` or simply do not understand the code behind it.

Comment: Could you merge breqn + mleftright + http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124464/incorrect-delimiter-size-in-math-mode ?

Comment: @David: Adding support for `breqn` (if possible) seems way too complex for `mleftright`. And adding analyzing and maintaining a complex package is nothing that I should put on my "ToDo" list. It is way too long already.