# Absolute values and height scaling on some symbols

Tags: vertical-alignment, scaling, height

I currently use a macro:

```
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}
```

in order to write absolute values, but I'm finding that when I combine this with \hat then the height is modified in an undesirable way:

```
\lvert \hat{x} \rvert, \quad \left\lvert \hat{x} \right\rvert, \quad \lvert \hat{\psi} \rvert, \quad \left\lvert \hat{\psi} \right\rvert
```

The first three all have equal height on the absolute values, but the last is significantly higher. I can only presume this is something unique to the symbol \psi with \hat as opposed to a generic letter (in this case x). Is there any way around this without defining another macro (e.g. \normalabs without the \left and \right) or is there a better way to handle this?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}

\begin{document}
    
    \[
    \lvert \hat{x} \rvert, \quad \left\lvert \hat{x} \right\rvert, \quad \lvert \hat{\psi} \rvert, \quad \left\lvert \hat{\psi} \right\rvert    
    \]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why use the `\left...` and `\right...`?  How about the same as the others...simply `\lvert` and `\rvert`?

Comment: I guess it's generally convenient, e.g. when working with summations and integrals to use \left and \right, otherwise the lines are too short. Should I define an \abs with a \bigabs which uses \left, \right?

Comment: You can use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124481). There is a religious disagreement on whether or not one should raise or lower delimiters, but at least for vertical bars it could be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update `\abs` to take an optional argument where you specify something different that will be used as the sizing-mechanism:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}% Not needed if you have an updated LaTeX as of Oct 2020.
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\abs}{o m}{
  \left\lvert
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {#2}% No optional argument
    {\vphantom{#1}\smash{#2}}% Use optional argument for height purposes only
  \right\rvert
}

\begin{document}
    
\[
  \abs{\hat{x}}, \quad 
    \abs{\hat{x}}, \quad 
    \lvert \hat{\psi} \rvert, \quad 
    \abs{\hat{\psi}}, \quad
    \abs[\hat{x}]{\hat{\psi}}
\]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - this works better than what I had in mind.